# Odds when throwing an unequal number of dice

Tags: probability, combinatorics, binomial-distribution

Suppose I throw N dice, and my opponent throws M dice.

What are the odds that I threw more sixes than he did?

Comment: What are the odds of throwing $n$ sixes in $N$ throws?

Comment: You will have to give specific numbers for **N** and **M** to get a specific answer. For example, to take a simple example: if **A** tosses **(n+1)** fair coins, and **B** tosses **n** fair coins, the somewhat unexpected result is that P(**A** gets more heads than **B**) = **1/2,** whatever the value of **n**

Answer (score 4):

$\textbf{Hint:}$ Assuming the die is unbiased, the probability of getting k or more sixes in N throws is 
$$
\sum_{i=k}^{N} { N \choose i}\Big( \frac{1}{6} \Big) ^{i} \Big( \frac{5}{6} \Big) ^{N-i}
$$